# Transfer only revision history from Google Code to GitHub

Tags: svn, git, github, google-code

We recently moved our project from Google Code to GitHub, but only wanted to move a part of it (up to say revision 600) so instead of using GitHub's built-in system to transfer an SVN repo over we just created the project out of a local project folder that was appropriate.

However, I'd like to transfer over the revision history up to a specific revision. Is there a way to do this? Note I don't want the existing code in the repo to be modified, I just wanted to bring the history over.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use GitHub’s SVN import feature.
2. Clone the new git repository.
3. Use `git reset` to rewind `master` to whichever commit you think it should be.
4. `git push --force`

Comment: Is there a way just to move the history though? We've already done work on the existing repo.

Comment: Planning on using svn2git, any tips?

Comment: I don’t understand what “just the history” is supposed to mean. What else is going to be converted when you convert the repository? Nor do I understand why you point out that you have done work – because, why else would you want to convert it? So I am thinking that either you are trying to ask a question that you are not explaining in a way I (and apparently others, per lack of answers) understand, or you did not understand my answer. What are you trying to do?